# HTML, ASP - Contact Form Won't Work

Tags: html, asp-classic

This is my contact form that I want to connect to email upon form submission. I have researched on the net to do it but I cannot seem to run the codes.

I have two files where one is the html codes and another consists of the asp codes.

Need help on this please. Will appreciate your guidance.

```html
<body>
<h3>Contact Form</h3>
  <form name="form1" method="post" action="process.asp">
    <label for="name">name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name"  name="name" placeholder="Your web id.."/>
    <br><br>
    <label for="deptID">Department ID</label>
    <input type="text" id="deptID" name="departmentID" placeholder="Your department ID..">
    <br><br>
    <label for="issue">Issue</label>
    <select id="issue" name="issue">
      <option value="">Non-Availability of Test Points</option>
      <option value="">Unable to Change Cycle Time Value</option>
      <option value="">Unable to Retrieve Report</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <label for="subject">Additional Message</label>
    <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>
      <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

This is the process.asp page.

```html
<%

formname = Request.Form("name")
formID = Request.Form("departmentID")
formquery = Request.Form("issue")
formsubject = Request.Form("subject")

Set Mail = Server.CreateObject("CDONTS.NewMail")

Mail.From = formname
Mail.FromName = formname


Mail.AddAddress "test@gmail.com"


Mail.Subject = "Form submitted from web site"


Bodytxt = "Details of Form submission :" & VbCrLf & VbCrLf
Bodytxt = Bodytxt & "Contact Name : " & formname & VbCrLf
Bodytxt = Bodytxt & "ID : " & formID & VbCrLf
Bodytxt = Bodytxt & "Query Entered : " & formquery & VbCrLf
Bodytxt = Bodytxt & "Subject Entered : " & formsubject


Mail.Body = Bodytxt


Mail.Username = "me@gmail.com"
Mail.Password = "password"


Mail.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
Mail.Port = "587"
Mail.Send


Set Mail = Nothing

%>
```

Comment: "Wont Work" is not very helpful. Do you get an error message, if so what? What is happening that shouldn't? What isn't happening that should?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, John P. Unfortunately, there are no errors but I guess 'Wont Work' is the best word to explain my situation, basically the ASP codes don't seem to run, where by when user clicks on the submit button, the page wont redirect to the mail page.

Comment: Add a `Response.Write "Sending Email` before setting your variables and `Response.Write "Email Complete"` after `Set Mail = Nothing` to at least see if the code is being run.

Comment: On I side note. I would be investigating migrating to ASP.net. Classic VBScript based ASP is very much getting to the end of it's useful life

Comment: CDONTS was deprecated in Windows 2000 and completely removed from Windows 2003.  CDOSYS is now the default component for sending emails in Classic ASP.  This is the best guide to using it I've found. http://www.powerasp.net/content/new/sending_email_cdosys.asp

Answer (score -1):

Not sure whats going on with your code snippets but they look extremely incomplete, you need a heap more than that to join an ASP page to a backend set of code.

A standard setup using C# and ASP.Net is the following. Say my page is called "Default.aspx"

This would be my (As you called is HTML, but really you mean your ASP)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And then joined to this would be the C# ASP.Net

That would look something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

What you have done above will never work, there is nothing referencing between the two files, your first piece of code is just plain html not ASP and there is nothing that defines your C# environment.

What I would suggest, get Visual Studio 2015 (Its free) and then click "New" and select ASP Website. Once you have done that click your new project and hit "Add Web Form" that will give you a good start, then you can start adding your form and code.

Caz

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Caz. I am currently working on a website and I do not require C#. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: You need to use a backend language, there is no way to use email in a form without a backend language. The most common are PHP or C#. There may be some API stuff you can do with javascript to email but I have never used them. So just remember, there is NO WAY to email without backend code.

Comment: Also, that code that is currently displayed in your snippet looks like vb.Net which is just C#'s simple cousin

Comment: Ugh my bad, I shouldn't have looked at the tags where he said ASP.Net

Comment: No worries, it was only a comment that alerted me to the fact it was classic asp.  I adjusted the tags accordingly

Comment: Xersex39 - go to https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/ - grab Visual Studio 2017 Community, there are billions of email forms that people have already made out there you can just plug and play.